# Zend Unable to connect to HTTPS server through proxy

Tags: php, zend-framework, proxy

I'm using Zend Framework 1.* and when executes the "stream_socket_enable_crypto" always returns false. Zend throws the exception this exception:

```
"Unable to connect to HTTPS server through proxy could not negotiate secure connection."
```

I've tried all the following crypto types in the previous method "stream_socket_enable_crypto" with the same result...

```
STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_SSLv2_CLIENT
STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_SSLv3_CLIENT
STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_SSLv23_CLIENT
STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_CLIENT
STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_SSLv2_SERVER
STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_SSLv3_SERVER
STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_SSLv23_SERVER
STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_SERVER
```

Looking deep into the "connectHandshake" Zend method I've seen I can connect to the proxy, but not to the server through the proxy. I'm stuck for long with this issue, any clue?

PHP version 5.6.*

Answer (score 2):

Finally realized was a problem of PHP version. **In PHP 5.6.* "verify_peer_name" default changed to TRUE**. See change log [here](http://php.net/manual/en/context.ssl.php#refsect1-context.ssl-changelog).

Setting this property to false solved the connection issue.

```
    $adapter->setStreamContext(array(
            'socket' => array(
                // Bind local socket side to a specific interface
                'bindto'            => self::PROXY_HOST . ':' . self::PROXY_PORT
            ),
            'ssl' => array(
                'crypto_method'     => STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_2_CLIENT,
                // Verify server side certificate,
                'verify_peer'       => false,
                'verify_peer_name'  => false,
                'allow_self_signed' => false,
            )
        )                
    );
```

Hope it helps someone else